# .toggle() is not working on appended element

Tags: jquery

I am working on a Mobile Menu. My code is like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hamburger").click(function () {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 1000) {
            $("#nav_links, #search_bar").slideToggle(1000); 
            $("#hamburger i").toggleClass('fa-bars').toggleClass('fa-times'); 

            $('.header-links').toggle("slide", { direction: "bottom" }, 1000);
            $('.links').toggle("slide", { direction: "bottom" }, 1000);
        }
    });

    $('.user-name').click(function () {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 1000) {
            $('.top_nav').toggle("slide", { direction: "bottom" }, 1000);  // this .toggle() is not working
            $('body header .dropdown-container ul.dropdown-menu').toggle("slide", { direction: "bottom" }, 1000);  // this .toggle() is not working
        }
    });
});
```

When I click on `.user-name` first time, `.top_nave` and `.dropdown-menu` is showing but if I click again then it is not hiding.

Here is my HTML code

```
<nav class="header-links top_nav">
            <ul id="nav_links" class="links text-center">
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>

                <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>

                <li><a href="">Membership</a></li>

                <li><a href="">One Off Support</a></li>

                <li><a href="">Coverage</a></li>

                <div class="dropdown-container" component="dropdown">
                    <span class="user-name py-s hide-under-l" refs="dropdown@toggle" aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">
                        DIY Guides
                    </span>
                    <ul refs="dropdown@menu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ url('/') }}"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24"
                                    viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                    <path
                                        d="M20 7.093l-3-3v-2.093h3v5.093zm4 5.907h-3v10h-18v-10h-3l12-12 12 12zm-10 2h-4v6h4v-6z" />
                                </svg>DIY Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a
                                href="{{ url('/categories') }}">@icon('bookshelf'){{ trans('entities.categories') }}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ url('/guides') }}">@icon('books'){{ trans('entities.guides') }}</a>
                        </li>
                        @if(!signedInUser())
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ url('/login')  }}">@icon('login'){{ trans('auth.log_in') }}</a>
                        <li>
                            @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('.user-name').click(function () {
   if (window.innerWidth <= 1000) {
      $('.top_nav').slideToggle("slow");
      $('body header .dropdown-container ul.dropdown-menu').slideToggle("slow");
   }
});
```